# Turning off keyboard popup

Tags: keyboard, macos, bluetooth

When I connect a bluetooth keyboard to my computer, it pops up this icon:

[image: keyboard popup]

Can I get rid of that?

Comment: I've never heard of or seen any way to do this, so I am tempted to say "no" but I am curious to see if maybe there is a way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to suppress it showing up, but are you saying it does not disappear after only a few seconds? If it stays on screen, then that is not normal behavior. When my bluetooth trackpad connects I get a similar icon for only a few seconds - it will appear also if I lose the connection, say from a weak battery.

Comment: It stays for only a few seconds. I just want it to never show up.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:  I have never tried this - though it should not hurt your system.**

You *could* remove `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin`... but removing this package would take all the bezel style interface items with it.  (volume up/down, brightness, remote paring, etc.)

Removing this package could have undesired effects, beyond just removing the bezels, but I can't think of any specifically...   It should work...  However, keep a copy of it, make note of the permissions, and put it back if it dorks other stuff up.

Also, expect later updates of OS X to replace this package...

Some may suggest viewing the contents of the package and removing just the bezels you don't want from `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/BezelUI/HiDPI` but I notice there is a _CodeSignature directory here: `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/_CodeSignature` and that may invalidate the entire package.

**After making whatever changes you want to the BezelServices.loginPlugin you should probably restart your computer, or at the very least log out and back in - before you will see the desired effect.**

Sorry for not providing a clearer answer.